# IndexOf не находит элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добавляю в массив элементы страницы (td), вывожу(console.log(arr);)(пример):

```
(2) [jQuery.fn.init(1), jQuery.fn.init(1)]
   0: jQuery.fn.init [tr.1539953619.hovered.on.used]
   1: jQuery.fn.init [tr.1539949435.hovered.on.used]
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array(0)
```

то есть, элементы добавляются правильно, дальше когда использую поиск элементов:

```
console.log(arr.indexOf($(this))); //$(this) потому что при клике если элемент не выбран (отсутствует класс used) добавляет элемент (arr[list.length] = $(this);) если нет - должно выводить его индекс
```

всегда выводит -1, хотя элементы там есть.
Почему может не работать и как исправить?

Comment: `list` и `arr` - это, видимо, одно и то же? В jQuery индекс ищется с помощью метода [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: @Regent, это другой index :)

Comment: @Grundy мм, другой - это какой? Я написал из расчета, что вместо массива jQuery объектов стоит использовать один, содержащий все элементы, после чего спокойно использовать `.index`

Comment: @Regent да, это один и тот же массив, просто не повсюду заменил на arr) чтоб тут наглядней было

Comment: @shumik_UA если нужно обязательно через список/массив (например, если он часто читается), то я за вариант из ответа Igor. Если список нужен всего один или несколько раз, то, в качестве альтернативы, факт нажатия можно хранить в самом элементе data-атрибутом, а при получении списка брать все элементы и отфильтровывать ненужные по значению data-атрибута

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` - вызов функции `$`/`jQuery`, который возвращает *новый*/*свежесозданный* объект-обертку вокруг набора DOM-элементов, в данном случае - одного элемента `this`. Такого объекта-ссылки не может существовать в массиве.

---

Храните в массиве ссылки на DOM-элементы:

```
list.push(document.getElementById("test"));
...
console.log(list.indexOf(this));
```

Comment: При первом нажатии на элемент - он добавляется в массив, при повторном нажатии - удаляется. При добавлении берется $(this) и при удалении тоже

Comment: @shumik_UA Это Вы с кем разговариваете? Это описание чего?

Comment: ну с вами, объясняю  что хочу сделать. Есть массив, и в нем выбранные элементы - как выбрать - первый раз нажал - выбрал - добавился в массив, второй раз нажал - удалил из массива, элемент не выбран

Comment: а разве document.getElementById("test") не равно в jquery $(this) (если имеется ввиду один и тот же элемент)

Comment: @shumik_UA Нет, не равно. Попробуйте еще раз медленно прочитать мой ответ ).

Comment: @shumik_UA объект, возвращаемый `document.getElementById("test")`, не равен объекту, возвращаемому `$(this)`. Это совершенно разные объекты с точки зрения JavaScript-a

Comment: Никогда раньше с этим не сталкивался,все время принимал что напр. document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'))  === $(this) то есть просто выбираешь элемент на странице, любым способом

Comment: @shumik_UA Вот видите, узнали что-то новенькое.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете с помощью jQuery, то не нужно смешивать его с чистым js.
Для сравление jQuery элементов  можно использовать is:

```
element1.is(element2)
```

Тогда для проверки есть ли элемент в массиве можно использовать что-то типа

```
arrayItems.some((element) => { return element.is(element2); }
```

Где element - это массива, а element2 - то что вы пытаетесь найти в массиве

А для того, чтобы найти элемент в массиве

```
let founded = arrayItems.filter((element) {
  return element.is(element2);
});
```